# Installation with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, system-installation, partitioning

I have already created my bootable flash drive and checked out Ubuntu.  I want to install it along side my Windows 8.1 Pro.  I have a 1 terabyte hard drive.  On this drive I have a 2 windows partitions and 195 gigabyte partition.

When I run the installation it does not see any partitions at all and just sees the whole drive as being free space.  I tried making a volume of my 195 gig free space and got the same result.  I need to have Windows 8 on my hard drive, what am I missing that the installation program does not see any partitions but just 1 terabyte free?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange because Ubuntu installer shows all the partitions whether they are NTFS or FAT32 or whatever. Try installing Ubuntu using a DVD if possible.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should first go to the disk manager in Windows and erase the partition you want to use for Linux, before booting from the flash drive. Then installation program should accept to use this free space to create the needed partitions.

HTH

Comment: Ok thanks I will give that a try delete the partition so it is just 195 gig of free space.  Then I will boot from flash drive and try the installation again.